# JS Conditional Template in Column

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and it makes this even more difficult for me.

I'm trying to put a condition in my column template but I can't get it to work. 
The code is this:

```
template: '@viewMode' == "EDIT" ? '<input class="equipDropDownEditor"/>' : "#:PROMOTION_TYPE#",
```

This almost shows what I want. The problem is that if the `Promotion_Type` field is null, it shows null on the screen.

So, the condition that I want to implement is: If the `viewmode` is `"edit"`, it will return the `equipDropDownEditor`.

In case it is not, it shows the field `PROMOTION_TYPE`. But, in case that `Promotion_Type` returns a null, I don't want it to show anything (empty string, for example.

This is what I have tried. Still got the null on the screen when the "viewMode" is not "EDIT".

```
template: '@viewMode' == "EDIT" ? '<input class="equipDropDownEditor"/>' : ("#:PROMOTION_TYPE#" == null ? " " : "#:PROMOTION_TYPE#"),
```

Comment: One thing that could have helped would have been to specify what templating engine this is for.
One thing you may try is to add quotes around the null in your test, as it seems like your promotion type is getting cast to a string before the comparison.

Comment: Cool, glad you made it work. You may answer the question yourself by the way, that will be even more useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help someone in the future, I got it working with: template:

```
'@viewMode' == "EDIT" ? '<input class="equipDropDownEditor"/>' : ("#:PROMOTION_TYPE#" == null ? " " : "#:PROMOTION_TYPE#" == "#:PROMOTION_TYPE#"),
```

Thanks anyway @Bertrand Le Roy